# How to position well items in HTML and CSS irrespective of zooming in or out?

Tags: html, css

In my following code, the items are well positioned when I am viewing them when opened in browser with 100% default zoom but they gets displaced when zoomed in browser, could you guide me on how to make them stick close to one another irrespective of screen size or zooming in?
Link to project github:
https://github.com/xafak/FrontEndMentor-Four_Card_Feature_Section

How it appears when not zoomed in:

[image: Text]

How it appears when zoomed in:

[image: Text]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Four card feature section</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top_container">
      <h1 class="first_heading">Reliable, efficient delivery</h1>
      <h1>Powered by Technology</h1>
      <h4 class="third_heading">
        Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data
        points to ensure that your project is successful
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="cards_container">
      <div class="supervisor_container">
        <div class="container_lower_part_all_cards">
          <h2>Supervisor</h2>
          <p>Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
        </div>
        <img
          class="specified_icon"
          src="images/icon-supervisor.svg"
          alt="icon_supervisor"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="teambuilder_container">
        <div class="container_lower_part_all_cards">
          <h2>Team Builder</h2>
          <p>
            Scans our talent network to crete the optimal team for your project
          </p>
        </div>
        <img
          class="specified_icon"
          src="images/icon-team-builder.svg"
          alt="icon_teambuilder"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="karma_container">
        <div class="container_lower_part_all_cards">
          <h2>Karma</h2>
          <p>
            Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality
          </p>
        </div>
        <img
          class="specified_icon"
          src="images/icon-karma.svg"
          alt="icon_karma"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="calculator_container">
        <div class="container_lower_part_all_cards">
          <h2>Calculator</h2>
          <p>
            Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates
          </p>
        </div>
        <img
          class="specified_icon"
          src="images/icon-calculator.svg"
          alt="icon_calculator"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by
      <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
        >Frontend Mentor</a
      >. Coded by <a href="https://github.com/xafak">Sanzar Farooq</a>.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 25rem;
}
.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200, 400, 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);

  display: inline-block;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.first_heading {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0;
}

.third_heading {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top_container {
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.cards_container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container_lower_part_all_cards {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.specified_icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 75%;
}

/* supervisor_container specifications*/

.supervisor_container {
  border-top: solid 7px;
  border-top-color: hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 2%;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 11rem;
}

/* teambuilder_container specifications*/

.teambuilder_container {
  border-top: solid 7px;
  border-top-color: hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 2%;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 13.3rem;
}

/* karma_container specifications*/

.karma_container {
  border-top: solid 7px;
  border-top-color: hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 2%;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 24rem;
  left: -13.5rem;
}

/* calculator_container specifications*/

.calculator_container {
  border-top: solid 7px;
  border-top-color: hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 2%;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 11.4rem;
  left: -11.5rem;
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this by using `display:flex` on `.cards_container`, currently your cards inside the containers are positioned using `left` and `top` values which is not helping you retain the position while you zoom/resize window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to simplify the layout.

```css
.cards_container {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  height: 200px; /* resized for demo purpose */
  min-width: 33.33%;
}

.card .card-inner {
 height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
/*define the margin for 2nd card based on your requirement*/
  margin-top: -145px;
}

.card:nth-child(4) {
/*define the margin for last card based on your requirement*/
  margin-top: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards_container">
  <div class="supervisor_container card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="teambuilder_container card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="karma_container card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator_container card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```